# Is there a way to get a Max/Min/Close Applet to Ubuntu Mate Panel?

Tags: panel, ubuntu-mate

I have Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and I choose the Mutiny layout, after that I added the `TopMenu Mate Panel Applet`, an applet that hides the menu from the application and displays it in the topmenu panel. In the Mate Tweak, I also enabled "Undecorate maximised windows". I am trying to make it look like Unity, for my laptop, screen space and all.

After enabled all that, you see it look like unity, except for the maximize minimize button, those are not at the top panel, and could not find it in the `Add to panel` window. My question is how do I add a max/min/close add-to-panel Applet!?

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: @krypron nope..

Comment: I found that I don't really need those as there are hotkeys for them. Now I have a single top bar with: Mate Menu, Top Menu Panel Applet, and Notification Area. I also use Numix theme set.

As for the hotkeys, I bind Win-Z to minimize, Win-X to toggle maximize. Now the desktop is very spacious and simplistic.